# How can I get the "bio" value of a "User" object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

I want to get the "bio" value from "User" object. The image below shows what I mean:

[The object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54dlc.png)

I get this object when I run this code using discordjs-selfbot-v13 npm.
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Jtw.png).

I tried to console it like that:

```
console.log(await member.getProfile().bio)
```

And like this too:

```
console.log(await member.getProfile()[0].bio)
```

And a lot of other code, but they didn't work.

Comment: Those are screenshots. pictures, of code; why did you take pictures of code instead of just sharing the code - formatted as code - as text? Please, post the code in the question, don't show pictures of it.

Comment: And you can edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74714489/how-to-get-bio-value-of-user-object-while-console-logawait-member-getprofile) to add more details.

Comment: A reference is *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*). Please review it and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74717769/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resolve the promise first:

```js
console.log((await member.getProfile()).bio)
```